# Disable push notification for a live app in AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I have a app in the AppStore, where I have push notification controlled from OneSignal. A few days ago, all my users started to receive notification about porn websites and such. I have over 10k that receives push notifications on my app. I deleted my account on OneSignal, but they still send out the notifications. Is there any way I can stop my app from receiving push notifications, without uploading a new version where I have to remove OneSignal? I just want to remove push notifications service from my live version of the app. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you revoked your push notification certificate in the apple developer site?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I just did that 30 minutes ago.